# Why is the ISO standard so for NULL when ANSI_NULL is set to ON?

Tags: sql-server

> When ANSI_NULL is set to ON:
>
> SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL return no rows
>
> and SELECT 1 WHERE NULL IS NULL returns one row

I understand the reason why the above queries return what they return. But I am curious to know why the rule is so. Why, according to ISO standard, NULL = NULL is UNKNOWN instead of TRUE? Why 'NULL = NULL gives TRUE' not taken as ISO standard? Is it because NULL value doesn't have a datatype? Or some other reason. I assume there must be some reason.

Comment: `NULL` really means 'unknown', you cannot judge whether something unknown is equal to some other unknown.

Comment: NULL means something we don't know. So we can't compare one unknow value with another using `=`. We can only say `IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators **do not** follow the ISO standard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql

What you describe in the question is exactly what you should expect if ANSI_NULLS is ON

The general standard that applies to NULL in SQL is that *you cannot determine the value of NULL*, therefore you also cannot know if it is equal to any value (because you are unable to determine one side of the predicate). If you can't figure out if NULL is equal to anything then it also follows that you cannot know if it is unequal either.

This is why SQL provide special methods for handling NULL:

SELECT 1 WHERE NULL **IS** NULL 
    SELECT 1 WHERE NULL **IS NOT** NULL